# How to populate a dropdown on click

Tags: php, jquery

I have  categories  and I want to display the categories with my dropdown when I click on the dropdown.

This approach does'nt work. What are the elements than I need to change inside the code ?

Thank you

my ajax php

```
    $Qcheck = $OSCOM_Db->prepare('select distinct categories_id as id,
                                                    categories_name as name
                                   from :table_catogories
                                  ');
    $Qcheck->execute();

    $list = $Qcheck->rowCount() ;

    if ($list > 0) {
      $array = [];

      while ($value =  $Qcheck->fetch() ) {
        $array[] = $value;
      }

    # JSON-encode the response
      $json_response = json_encode($array); //Return the JSON Array

    # Return the response
      echo $json_response;
```

now my files

```
        <?php
          $categories_ajax = OSCOM::link('categories_ajax.php');
        ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
          function myAjax() {
            $("#myAjax").on('click', function(){
              $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo $categories_ajax; ?>',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                  //data returned from php
                }
              });
            )};
        </script>
// my dropdown
         <?php echo HTML::selectMenu('move_to_category_id', CategoriesAdmin::getCategoryTree(), 'onclick="myAjax()"') . HTML::hiddenField('current_category_id', $current_category_id); ?>
```

note `CategoriesAdmin::getCategoryTree()` display the categories name. it's an array

my dropdown function element

```
public static function selectMenu($name, array $values, $default = null, $parameters = '', $required = false, $class = 'form-control') {}
```

Comment: Can you describe further the problem and post the error that you are getting? Other thing, you seems not consuming the data returned by your ajax request.

Comment: is this `from :table_catogories` 1st: only a typo here, 2nd why the `:`? You can't 'prepare' a table name.

Comment: there are so many things we can't know. Why is `selectMenu()` empty??
 What is `$categories_ajax` resolving to? _Please post the final html/js of your frontend._

Comment: and describe what _"does'nt work"_ mean to you. Is the script called at all? Returning unexpected data or no data?